# Callback with reference to itself vs. standalone subclass

Tags: android

Maybe stupid question, but I can't understand...
Is there a difference between the following ways?
I mean waste memory or something?

```
class A implements Handler.Callback {
    // is it OK to pass the loopback reference into the Handler in this case?
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(this); 
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
         ...
    }
}

class B {
    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             ...
         }
    };
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on your desired usage. If you have just one button and need to handle its click, I would use an anonymous class (like in your `class B`). But if a view contains lots of buttons or other things, you want to handle click events for, I would use the first method with one single handler for all controls. This saves you creating an extra object for each control (coding and memory overheap), too!

I am using this way in a project currently, having my activity handling every click and then doing the further work:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

...

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        // handle button 1
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        // handle button 2
        break;
        // ...
    }
}
...
}
```